# How to remove Site Name from page title

Tags: 7, theming, google-analytics

I'm using Omega 7.3x to theme my site, and at current, all the page headers are

[Page Title] | [Site Name]

but I'm trying to bring back google analytics reports into the site so the admin can see a list of the most active pages etc, except all the reports have the same pattern, it makes reading the report more difficult

eg, the report looks like

- My Account | My Website
- Fixtures | My Website
- Events | My Website
- Contact | My Website

I want to either remove the Site name from the page title, or just so that Google Analytics doesn't pick it up, I assume the latter is better to do in terms of SEO etc, how do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Use https://www.drupal.org/project/metatag module to modify page titles (among other things) per content or content type.

To modify what google analytics displays as title is beyond the scope of this forums